# AQGridView: CellChoser

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cell, aqgridview

I implemented AQGridView, and works Fine, but when I select an cell, she disappears.

I think this is related with method "cellChooser"

What is the function of CellChoser?

```
- (void) cellChooser: (MagazineCell *) chooser selectedItemAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index
```

And how can I do implement it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

cellChooser  (in ImageDemo) is just a delegate to handle the popover that switches the cell display type (between Plain and Filled), so you can see two different styles.  It's part of the demo app, not the framework, and unless you're doing a similar popover, you don't need to implement it.

The actual function called when you select a cell in your GridView is - (void) gridView: (AQGridView *) gridView didSelectItemAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index;

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/RadhikaS/AQGridView/tree/ here you are